# How do you render dynamic HTML or SVG in Qwik?

Tags: jsx, qwik

I get SVG or dynamic HTML from a headless CMS. But I can't render it in Qwik.

In Next.js we would use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for this purpose.

What is our option in Qwik? I can't find anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";

export default component$(() => (
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 6a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0zM4.501 20.118a7.5 7.5 0 0114.998 0A17.933 17.933 0 0112 21.75c-2.676 0-5.216-.584-7.499-1.632z" />
</svg>
`}
  ></div>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { QwikIntrinsicElements } from '@builder.io/qwik'

export function ArrowForwardIcon(props: QwikIntrinsicElements['svg'], key: string) {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" {...props} key={key}><path fill="currentColor" d="m12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8l-8-8z"></path></svg>
  )
}
export default ArrowForwardIcon
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?